# How to add custom js & css for specific pages

Tags: magento-1.9, category, layout-update, js-css

I trying to ***add custom js & css  only for all category pages.***

I create a `local.xml` file  at `app/design/frontend/package/theme/layout/local.xml`
& add this code inside it.

```
< ?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
     <catalog_category_default>
         <reference name="head">
             <action method="addItem">
                  <type>skin_js</type><name>js/myjavascript.js</name>
             </action>
             <action method="addItem">
                   <type>skin_css</type><name>css/mycss.css</name>
             </action>
         </reference>            
     </catalog_category_default>
</layout>
```

But I don't get that files in head section. So my question is *how to add custom css & js files for all category pages ?*

Comment: and what is the question?

Comment: you are not able to add it ?

Comment: you can try the answers and check which is posted

Answer (score 10):

The category pages can use 2 layout handles depending on the 'is_anchor' flag of the category.
`catalog_category_default` is used when `is_anchor` is `no` and `catalog_category_layered` is used when `is_anchor` is `yes`.
But there is one layout handle that is loaded, but magento does not use it in it's files.
`<catalog_category_view>`.

So you can try with this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <catalog_category_view>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_js</type><name>js/myjavascript.js</name>
            </action>
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_css</type><name>css/mycss.css</name>
            </action>
         </reference>            
     </catalog_category_view>
</layout>
```

Comment: +1 for that special `catalog_category_view` layout handle. I will definitely try that layout handle when a situation comes. :-)

Comment: I followed your answer, my js is inside skin/frontemd/ucs_personalizaion/js/person.js, but in page source magento looks the js inside base/default.. directory, can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
<catalog_category_layered>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_js</type> 
            <name>js/myjavascript.js</name> 
        </action>
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_css</type> 
            <file>css/mycss.css</file> 
        </action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add CSS file follow the below steps:

```
Open File
app\design\frontend\rwd\default\layout\page.xml
Add the below tag for css:
<action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/[filename].css</stylesheet></action>

Just below the last method=”addCss” add the above line.
Now open,
skin\frontend\rwd\default\css\[filename].css

Start writing your css code in this file.
```

To add JS file follow the below steps.

```
Open File
app\design\frontend\rwd\default\layout\page.xml
Add the below tag
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/[filename].js</name></action>

Just below the js include tags similar to the above line.
Now open,
skin\frontend\rwd\default\js\[filename].js

Start writing your js code in this file
```

Question is same as [#226981](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/61334/how-to-add-custom-css-file-to-head/226981#226981)