# Magento 1.9 : Add custom css file to head

Tags: magento-1.9, css

I need to add a custom CSS file to Magento that then is used site-wide. I know you have to add this to a **local.xml** file, however, the stylesheet I add is just not loaded.

Anyone that can help?

Here is what I've added to my **local.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0">
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addCss”><type>skin_css</type><file>css/javcustom.css</file></action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

I know there are a lot of topics on this here, but I've tried all of them and I just can't get it to work...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are two way to add css to head `one is  using function` `addCss`
 and another is **addItem**. You have mix-up two format.
Your format is wrong.

try this

```
<action method="addCss">
    <stylesheet>css/javcustom.css</stylesheet>
</action>
```

instead of

```
<action method="addCss">
    <type>skin_css</type>
    <file>css/javcustom.css</file>
</action>
```

or try this

```
<action method="addItem">
    <type>skin_css</type>
    <name>css/javcustom.css</name>
</action>
```

Comment: good amit bera.

Comment: I tried them, but they don't seem to load. When looking at my page source, they just don't show up...

Comment: nvm, it worked, there was a typo in what I've typed ;)

Comment: Confirmed, working for me too!

Answer (score 3):

To add CSS file follow the below steps:

```
Open File
app\design\frontend\rwd\default\layout\page.xml
Add the below tag for css:
<action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/[filename].css</stylesheet></action>

Just below the last method=”addCss” add the above line.
Now open,
skin\frontend\rwd\default\css\[filename].css

Start writing your css code in this file.
```

To add JS file follow the below steps.

```
Open File
app\design\frontend\rwd\default\layout\page.xml
Add the below tag
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/[filename].js</name></action>

Just below the js include tags similar to the above line.
Now open,
skin\frontend\rwd\default\js\[filename].js

Start writing your js code in this file.
```

For Magento 2 please refers to [this link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108685/how-to-add-a-custom-css-file-in-magento-2).