# custom css file loads last in magento 2

Tags: magento2

directory structure.

app / design / frontend / Kidzie / theme / Magento_Theme / layout /default_head_blocks.xml
 app / design / frontend / [vendor] / [theme] / web / css /custom.css

I need to load custom.css file at last of all css files. so my custom style should apply over default magento 2's css.

[image]

`<css src="css/custom.css" order="100"/>`  Gives me error that order is not a valid property.

Comment: If you want to defer the JS please refer this extension https://marketplace.magento.com/bitware-speedenginedeferjs.html

Answer (score 1):

**Magento2** doesn't manage the CSS order, `order=""` property doesn't exists,

> The available **CSS** attributes are:
>
> - defer
> - ie_condition
> - charset
> - hreflang
> - media
> - rel
> - rev
> - sizes
> - src
> - src_type
> - target
> - type

I have some workaround to put the css at the end of all. the trick is to add `media="all"`.

```
<css src="css/custom.css" media="all" />
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, it make my custom css run between style-m.css and style-l.css, version magento 2.3.5-p1.

Answer (score 0):

Please first study, this [Load Custom CSS After style-l.css For Home Page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/217131/load-custom-css-after-style-l-css-for-home-page/217180#217180) article. Here [Rajeev K Tomy](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/3535/rajeev-k-tomy?tab=profile) explain the load sequence of CSS at Magento2.

As you want to call  your css at last, So you have done some changes  at

**default_head_blocks.xml**

```
<css src="Magento_Theme::css/custom.css" media="all" />
```

It means to you have to change your css file location to

```
app / design / frontend / [vendor] / [theme] /Magento_Theme/ web / css /custom.css
```

**Then you have to do cache flush and static content deploy.**

Comment: This doesn't work for me, it make my custom css run between style-m.css and style-l.css, version magento 2.3.5-p1.

Answer (score 0):

If other solutions doesn't work, you can try this (this is just a workaround until we find a correct way to do this):

 Create styles-l.css in your theme, then move your css code to the created file, then run deploy command so the code will go to bottom of file styles-l.css after the deploy.

> app/design/frontend/Kreativsohne/Werbemittel24/web/css/styles-l.css

[image]

Hope it's help.

Answer (score 0):

in default.xml

```
<referenceContainer name="head.additional">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"
               name="nd_custom_head"
               after="-"
               template="Magento_Theme::html/load_last_head.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
```

IN Magento_Theme/templates/html/load_last_head.phtml

```
<?php

/** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template $block */

$href = trim($block->getViewFileUrl("Magento_Theme::css/custom_style.css"));
echo '<link defer rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' . $href . '">';
```

and create a file css/custom_style.css

It will load at last of CSS that is for sure

Happy coding