# How to extend gallery.css in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, frontend, less

How do you extend `gallery.css` in Magento2?

`gallery.css` is loaded after `styles-m.css` so anything that I put in my theme's `_extend.less` the file gets overwritten by it.

I don't want to override everything in it, just a few CSS rules.

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy this file below and paste to this folder on you custom theme:

**from**

```
lib/web/mage/gallery/gallery.less
```

**to**

```
app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{Theme}/web/mage/gallery/gallery.less
```

Yes it will override, but now you can add a new extend property, like this last line below, after the natives lines, then you can create a new LESS files:

```
@import 'module/_variables.less'; //Default gallery variables
@import '../../css/source/lib/_lib.less'; // Global lib
@import '../../css/source/_theme.less'; // Theme overrides
@import '../../css/source/_variables.less'; // Local theme variables
@import '../../css/source/lib/_responsive.less';
@import 'module/_mixins.less'; //Mixins in gallery
@import 'module/_extends.less';
@import 'module/_focus.less';
@import 'module/_fullscreen.less';
@import 'module/_custom.less'; //Your custom LESS
```

---

This file is called here `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`, if you want add a new CSS in the sequence just create to your custom template:

```
app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{Theme}/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml
```

And add your **custom.css** for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="mage/gallery/gallery.css"/>
        <css src="Magento_Catalog::css/custom.css"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I would take the few CSS rules that you want to overwrite out of `_extend.less` and put them in a custom CSS file. Then, add that CSS file to the `default_head_blocks.xml` file in `Magento_Theme` extension.

Specifics on how to add custom CSS and have it load last (to overwrite `gallery.css`) can be found [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108685/how-to-add-a-custom-css-file-in-magento-2).