# Magento2 Keeping CSS changes after redeployment

Tags: magento2, css, grunt, less-compilation

Hi I am new to Magento 2, I was wondering what methods people are using to keep CSS changes after they deploy static content as CSS changes are overwritten every time.

Thanks!

Comment: I think it'd be beneficial to explain whether it's ALL css changes or only a couple rules you've set up that seem to be overwritten, more details would be a very good idea to add to this question, as far as i'm aware my CSS changes don't change after redeployment

Comment: Mainly design changes to a templates CSS files, they are located in pub/static and are overwritten everytime you deploy static content

Comment: Never work in static folder files.

Comment: I give you steps

Comment: As Sourva points out, first thing's first never work in the static files, you want to overwrite CSS from your theme

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108685/how-to-add-a-custom-css-file-in-magento-2 you may want to refer to this answer on how to set up custom CSS.

Answer (score 2):

***Never* work in cache css files in pub/static folder. Files under this folder always overwritten when deploy command is run.**

Option:
**Installing and configuring Grunt**

Magento has built-in Grunt tasks configured, but there are still several prerequisite steps you need to take to be able to use it:

Install node.js to any location on your machine.
Install Grunt CLI tool globally. To do this, run the following command in a command prompt:

**npm install -g grunt-cli**

Install (or refresh) the node.js project dependency, including Grunt, for your Magento instance. To do this, run the following commands in a command prompt:
**cd 
npm install**

Add your theme to Grunt configuration. To do this, in the dev/tools/grunt/configs/themes.js file, add your theme to module.exports like following:

```
module.exports = {

    <theme>: {
        area: 'frontend',
        name: '<Vendor>/<theme>',
        locale: '<language>',
        files: [
            '<path_to_file1>', //path to root source file
            '<path_to_file2>'
        ],
        dsl: 'less'
    ...
    },
```

After configure run following commands:

**grunt clean:**
 eg: customtheme is name of my theme

Republishes symlinks to the source files to the pub/static/frontend/// directory.

**grunt exec:**

Compiles .css files using the symlinks published in the pub/static/frontend/// directory

**grunt less:**

Tracks the changes in the source files, recompiles .css files, and reloads the page in the browser pages

**grunt watch**

Comment: I don't think resorting to Node.JS or Grunt would at all be beneficial, the key information required to answer is how to create a theme and use your css in that theme

Comment: are you working directly css files under static folder ??

Comment: No, this answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108685/how-to-add-a-custom-css-file-in-magento-2 explains how you should add custom css.