# How to add custom css file in magento2.2.6?

Tags: css, magento2.2.6, styles

I tried to add some custom styles in Magento but I couldn't find out how to do this.

How do I add the custom css stylesheets in magento-2.2.6?

Comment: It may help you https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/108690/21339

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a custom CSS file in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108685/how-to-add-a-custom-css-file-in-magento-2)

Comment: @Dhiren Vasoya, i have edited the description, plz reopen it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to follow the below steps:

**Step 1:**
Create **default_head_blocks.xml** like below:

> app/design/frontend/[vendor]/[theme]/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

**Step 2:**
Andd create **local.css** like below

> app/design/frontend/[vendor]/[theme]/web/css/local.css

**Step 3:**
Add the below code to **default_head_blocks.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../vendor/magento/framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
  <head>
    <css src="css/local.css" />
  </head>
</page>
```

Comment: This is the most straightforward answer kudos!

Answer (score 5):

You have to add it in your current theme like this:

1. > app/design/frontend/{Yourtheme}/{name}/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

   ```
   <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../vendor/magento/framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
       <head>
           <css src="css/local.css" />
       </head>
   </page>
   ```
2. > app/design/frontend/{Yourtheme}/{name}/web/css/local.css

   ```
   Your css code goe here
   ```
3. Deploy the static content:

   ```
   php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
   ```

Comment: @nukala satish  what did not work ?

Comment: When i tried this in magento2.2.6. its not working brother