# Do I have to be in developer mode?

Tags: magento2, css, luma-theme, developer-mode, production-mode

[How to add custom css file in magento2.2.6?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/232726/how-to-add-custom-css-file-in-magento2-2-6)

I am in **Production mode**, using **Luma Magento 2.2.6**.

Do I have to be in Developer mode to make the solution in the above link work?

Before switching to Developer I have to clear the contents of :

```
var/cache  
generated/metadata  
generated/code  
var/view_preprocessed  
pub/static
```

But my file structure is different I can never seem to find the correct folders.

I know this is a beginner question but I really appreciate your professional expertise and guidance on this 7 month long obstacle I keep running into.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You don't need to be in `developer mode.`
If you are in `developer mode`, changes you made will apply immediately.
If you are in `production mode`, changes directly will not apply.
You need to `rm -rf var/cache,  rm -rf generated rm -rf var/view_preprocessed`
run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Comment: It looks like I don't have permissions to these files.

Comment: Can I make changes to the less files,  style-m.css and style-l.css? If so, do I have to be in developer mode to do this?

Comment: I am in Production mode.  I ran the rm -rf codes mentioned above in the CLR and got this error for all three: >>>

  [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
  Command "rm" is not defined.

  Did you mean this?
      setup:performance:generate-fixtures

Answer (score 0):

### Add the following folders to your custom theme

```
 app / design / frontend / [vendor] / [theme] / Magento_Theme / layout  
 app / design / frontend / [vendor] / [theme] / web / css
```

### Create the following Files

```
app / design / frontend / [vendor] / [theme] / Magento_Theme / layout / default.xml  
app / design / frontend / [vendor] / [theme] / web / css / yourcustom.css
```

### Place this code within **`default.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="css/yourcustom.css" />
    </head>
</page>
```

### Apply your theme

### Don't forget to run `setup:upgrade` before deploying `static-content` (sometimes deploying static:content directly doesn't apply changes)

Comment: Thank you so much. I will give this a try and get back to you all.

Comment: Is this the order I should follow?  1) Change to developer mode ; 2) create the above file structure ; 3) Then run set:upgrade. 4) delete var/cache, var/generation , and var/page_cache/ ; 5) switch back to production; 6) proceed to fill in content?

Comment: Sorry I am such a newb...

Comment: So I changed to developer mode, created the file structure above, added the xml file , ran  setup:upgrade, deleted the content of var/cache and var/page_cache folders, ran setup:upgrade again, made a test ID class in  "css/yourcustom.css" , created an element in with the ID name in page in the CMS , saved, cleared cache, reindexed, viewed page in browser but did not see any ID style changes from the " css/yourcustom.css " file.

Comment: I really appreciate this advice and help you have given me.  I am learning a lot but  can't seem to make it work. I will keep trying. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Use a **developer mode** when you are customizing the Magento

Use a **production mode** when you want to deploy your Magento on production

The big differences between the both modes:

**Developer mode:**

- `Static view` files are not cached; they are written to the Magento `pub/static` directory every time they’re called
- An exception is thrown in the error handler, rather than being logged
- System logging in var/report is verbose

**Production mode:**

- `Static view` files are served from the cache only.
- Errors are logged to the file system and are never displayed to the user.
- You cannot enable or disable cache types using the Magento Admin
- Does not allow you to enable or disable cache types in Magento Admin

So, you are customizing the Magento, you need to be in Developer Mode.

More information in [Magento Devdocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/bootstrap/magento-modes.html).

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you PЯINCƏ. I changed to Developer mode, then followed the above instructions best I could but couldn't get it to work yet.  Couldn't I change the style-l.css and style-m.css files? or some how add my_custom.css to the: /public_html/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/css/ folder? Thank you

Comment: How you added your `customstyle.css` ?

Comment: Manually, backend with FTP and as css not less.