# Add Bootstrap to magento 2.2.5

Tags: magento-2.2.5

I have to add bootstrap 3 or 4 to my custom theme (magento 2.2.5)
I tried this:
[How to use bootstrap in my custom theme](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/bootstrap/magento-bootstrap.html)
and this
[Bootstrap in magento 2 theme](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/195508/how-to-use-bootstrap-in-my-custom-theme/#answer-195553)
but these ways don't work with magento 2.2.5

```
<head>  
    <css src="css/bootstrap.css" />
    <css src="css/bootstrap.css.map" />
    <css src="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <css src="css/bootstrap.min.css.map" />
    <css src="css/bootstrap-grid.css" />
    <css src="css/bootstrap-grid.css.map" />
    <css src="css/bootstrap-grid.min.css" />
    <css src="css/bootstrap-grid.min.css.map" />
    <css src="css/bootstrap-reboot.css" />
    <css src="css/bootstrap-reboot.css.map" />
    <css src="css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css" />
    <css src="css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css.map" /></head>
```

default_head_blocks.xml (head section)

```
var config = {
paths: {
        'bootstrap':'Magento_Theme/js/bootstrap.bundle',
} ,
shim: {
    'bootstrap': {
        'deps': ['jquery']
    }
}
```

};

Magento_Theme/requirejs-config.js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        require(['bootstrap']);
    </script>
```

Magento_Theme/templates/html/header.phtml
Also I added Bootstrap css flies at (vendor/my_theme/web/css)
and added Bootstrap js files at (vendor/my_theme/Magento_Theme/web/js)
I use bootstrap 4 and magento 2.2.5

Comment: No answers Please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add custom css file in magento2.2.6?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/232726/how-to-add-custom-css-file-in-magento2-2-6)

Comment: Please mention your code.

Comment: please check the code

Answer (score 1):

The best way to include **js** is with **Requirejs**.

> app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/web/js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js

```
//bootstrap.min.js content
```

> app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    deps: [
        'js/output'
    ],
    paths: {
        'bootstrap': 'Magento_Theme/js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min',
    },
    shim: {
        'bootstrap': {
            'deps': ['jquery']
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

**Add your Bootstrap file in,**

> app\design\frontend\vendor-name\theme-name\web\css\bootstrap.css

**And call that files in your layout file like in,**

> app\design\frontend\vendor-name\theme-name\Magento_Theme\layout\default_head_blocks.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <!--Bootstrap css-->
        <css src="css/bootstrap.css" />
    </head>
</page>
```

Comment: bootstrap does include js

Comment: I did that but bootstrap doesn't work on my version 2.2.5

Answer (score -1):

Follow the below steps to add bootstrap files in your custom theme

> 1.Create `default_head_blocks.xml`

***app/design/frontend/vendor-name/theme-name/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml***

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
     <!--
      /**
      * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
      * See COPYING.txt for license details.
      */
     -->   
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>      
        <css src="css/bootstrap.css" />            
    </head>
</page>
```

2. Add your bootstrap CSS and js files from the following file paths below

> app/design/frontend/vendor-name/theme-name/web/css/web/css/bootstrap.css

3. Execute deploy commands from the command line.

> ```
> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
> php bin/magento setup:di:compile
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
> php bin/magento cache:flush && chmod -R 777 var generated
> ```

Comment: I did that but bootstrap doesn't work

Answer (score -2):

Follow below steos in order to include Bootstrap

1) upload your JS/CSS at below path

> /app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/web/css
>
> /app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/web/js

2) include files using default_head_blocks.xml

> app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml
>   add these line of code

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
          <css src="css/bootstrap.css" />
          <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

3) Execute following commands

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Here is the doc :

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-themes.html

Comment: I did that but bootstrap doesn't work

Comment: Edited my answer please check. It's working for me

Comment: Maybe you version older

Comment: My version is 2.2.5

Comment: Please mentioned your code in question.

Comment: Please check the code