# Why there is white space in products category as I have disabled some unused categories. I don't want these white spaces

Tags: magento2.3.3

[image]

I have installed Porto theme and using magento version 2.3.3

Comment: i think is category css effect. so remove width

Comment: From product category @MohitPatel

Comment: you apply css only

Comment: @MohitPatel Please be specific as I am new in magento2. Please tell from where I should apply css?

Comment: you create any custom theme  or  css file??

Comment: @MohitPatel No,I just installed Porto theme

Comment: go to your theme path and find web/css folder and add to custom css

Comment: check how to create custom css- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/232726/how-to-add-custom-css-file-in-magento2-2-6