# Magento 2 : How to move the search box next to logo title [SOLVED]

Tags: magento2, header

I'm using Magento 2 and trying to change the header part of the theme. I want the search box next to the logo Title "Electro store" as shown in image also i want to know how to change the css of search box and add a submit button by removing search icon and advance search link.

"Electro Store" Title is CMS Static Block which i've created in admin panel and used below code in **/var/www/html/magento226/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/header/logo.phtml**,

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('Electro-Title')->toHtml();?>
```

Below code is showing me search box in header links(next to register and login links),

```
<move element="top.search" destination="header.panel" before="-"/>
```

I tried to add `float:left;` css to block-search class in **styles-l.less** file,as suggested in this forum [Move Search Bar](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/Move-Search-Bar-Mag-2-2-3/td-p/92956) but that's not working. Everytime i run this command `php bin/magento cache:flush` in terminal it removes the changes in file.

Let me know if anyone have solution or query about question.

[image]

Comment: but i would still like to know how to do with `<move>` tag without using css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found a solution.**

I created **_extend.less** file under

> /var/www/html/magento226/app/design/frontend/Rock/Electro/web/css/source/_extend.less

where i made my custom changes

```
.block-search
{ 
   float:left; 
}
```

and it **worked**.

Answer (score 0):

You have done it right but add your own css for any customiztion of css otherwise it will gone when you update your magento or theme.

You can add your css by [this link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108685/how-to-add-a-custom-css-file-in-magento-2)

Thank you