# Magento 2 custom CSS is not loading after set new custom theme set on customer login

Tags: magento2, css, custom-theme

I set magento 2 luma theme for entire site if customer not login after customer login need set ultimo theme i have installed ultimo theme i am able to set 
by using fallowing line 
`$objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\View\DesignInterface::class)->setDesignTheme('Infortis/pawan', 'frontend');`

all working fine but when I write custom CSS it not loading it generating in pub folder but not loading
I have place custom CSS **Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml**

my XML file

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="css/font-awesome.min.css" />
         <css src="css/test.css" />

    </head>
</page>
```

but in frontend when I login all phtml files and other files loading but CSS and js not loading any idea how

in magento 1 by using below code I can set easily I want same in magento 2 any idea 
`Mage::getDesign()->setArea('frontend')->setPackageName('tricore')->setTheme('pawan');`.

Answer (score 0):

Also check that your custom css `is found` or give `404 error`.

Go to view code, find your `css/test.css` path and click it. Here you can check that css is found or it gives 404 error.

Comment: no it not showing in browser

Comment: It means your given css path is not right.  please refer this link  
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108685/how-to-add-a-custom-css-file-in-magento-2

Comment: given right path web/css/test.css