# Edit custom module on Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.0

I would like to ask if there is a way to override the design of the custom 3rd party module in magento 2 where I can put my own design and still fetch the data from the database. I'd appreciate any help with regards to this. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can add your own custom css file and override the module css.Refer below for more guidelines.
[How to add a custom CSS file in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108685/how-to-add-a-custom-css-file-in-magento-2)

Comment: this is helpful

Comment: I have tried this but the design does not change. I am using a 3rd party checkout module. IWD Agency. I plan to do my own custom module but my problem now is how to fetch the data to my own design

Answer (score 1):

if you need any specific function from custom module you can easily get by injecting class of Custom Module in Your Module.

```
class yourClass extends parentCLass
{
    public function __construct(
        \Vendor\CustomModule\Block\Class $customClass,
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
    ) {
        $this->customClass   =   $customClass;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function execute()
    {
       \\use specfic funtio
        $this->customModule->neededFuntion(); 

    }
}
```

If you want to entrupt a function and do your own task you can use `Plugin`

In your

> vendor\yourModule\etc\frontend\di.xml

```
<type name="Vendor\CustomModule\Block\Class>
       <plugin name="your_custom_plugin" type="Vendor\YourModule\Plugin\YourPlugin" sortOrder="10"/>
</type>
```

Now in

> Vendor\YourModule\Plugin\YourPlugin

```
class YourPlugin
{
    public function __construct(
    ) {
    }
    \\ Here you can override any funtion from the custom Module By Follwing hree ways
    public function beforeCuntomFuntion(
    }
    public function aroundCuntomFuntion(
    }
    public function afterCuntomFuntion(
    }
}
```