# Creating child theme how will I add css for extensions I have installed

Tags: css, parent-child-theme

I am newbie in Magento.
Template monster theme has already been installed and along with that I have  installed many extensions.
Now for adding custom css I have installed child theme .

I am not asking how will I add CSS in child theme

The question is If I want to add custom css for specific extension then how can I do that in child theme?

Comment: Refer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108685/how-to-add-a-custom-css-file-in-magento-2

Comment: I was asking if I want to add css to Extension which I have installed...How will I do that in Child theme? Is It same as I add it for parent theme css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I did not get your question wrong.
In your child theme, you can always fallback to the extension that you wanna add or override CSS.

For example, let's take a look at what is inside of the Paypal module in the Magento Luma:

```
└── web
    └── css
        └── source
            └── module
                ├── _billing.less
                ├── _paypal-button.less
                └── _review.less
```

So basically you will have:

```
Theme-Folder
    └── Vendor_Module
            └── web
                └── css
                    └── source
                        └── module
                            └── _your-css.less
```

Lemme know if is this what you meant.

Comment: Yes This is what I what I was asking about how to add css in module when child theme is activated