# Add external stylesheet link-rel head tag

Tags: ce-1.9.2.4, link, head, external, styles

Knewb here, I want to add **external stylesheets** via *link rel* to the *head tag* list of my store in version 1.9.  I am also using Ultimo theme.

> - Can it be done?
> - What is the name of the file I am looking for *(local.xml?)* ?
> - What is the path where it is located ?
> - How is the code written ?
> - How does the code work ?
> - Any other information that might help.

Currently my `custom.css` file is getting extremely long and fragile.

I know I am asking for a lot but any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

#### Local Css

1. You can download that css file for exemple `newcssfile.css` , then you add it in :

   > skin/frontend/{package}/{themeName}/css/newcssfile.css
2. Magento doesn't know this new file, so you have to declare it in :

   > app/design/frontend/{package}/{themeName}/layout/local.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <layout version="0.1.0">
       <default>
           <reference name="head">
               <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/newcssfile.css</name></action>
           </reference>
       </default>
   </layout>
   ```

#### External Css

> app/design/frontend/{package}/{themeName}/layout/local.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <block type="core/text" name="external-css-1">
                 <action method="setText">
                     <text><![CDATA[<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://path-to-your-external-newcssfile.css">]]></text>
                 </action>
             </block>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

**Note:** if you already have the `local.xml` file, you just add the piece of code between `<reference name="head">...</reference>` in that `<reference name="head">` block.

> Currently my `custom.css` file is getting extremely long and fragile.

You have to create another css file, follow the same steps 1&2 of `Local Css` part, just change the css name  for exemple `styledond.css` in : `skin/frontend/{package}/{themeName}/css/styledond.css`, and `<action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/styledond.css</name></action>`

Good luck.

Comment: This is Awesome thank you so much Price. I will report back thank you.

Comment: I was able to try this out today. Should I take the CDATA out so it reads: <text><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://path-to-your-external-newcssfile.css"></text>   ?

Comment: Yes, keep the CDATA, I tested it and it works for me

Answer (score 0):

If you have custom css file then you can add it in your theme local.xml file. You can read out this post for help:

[Magento 1.9 : Add custom css file to head](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/61334/magento-1-9-add-custom-css-file-to-head)

If it is external file then you can add it from admin, in web->design block head section.

Comment: I am going to try this out tomorrow. I'll report back

Answer (score 0):

You can edit file here:

> /app/design/frontend/ultimo/default/layout/local.xml

Add below code in head section.

```
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/custom.css</name><params/></action>
```

Then add your `custom.css` below location

> /skin/frontend/ultimo/default/css/custom.css