# Adding css to magento 1.8.1

Tags: magento-1.8, css

I'm trying to add a custom CSS file when a Magento action is loaded.

My layout page is as follows :

```
<layout version="0.1.0">

<helloworld_index_index>
  <reference name="head">

        <action method="addCss">
            <stylesheet>css/custom.css</stylesheet>
        </action>
    </reference>
       <reference name="root">
         <block type="page/html" name="root"  output ="toHtml" template = "mypage.phtml"/>

     </reference>

</helloworld_index_index>
</layout>
```

The content of mypage.phtml displays without a problem but the CSS is not loaded.
The path to my css is :

> skin\frontend\base\default\css\custom.css

Comment: Check these links https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/61334/magento-1-9-add-custom-css-file-to-head OR https://www.simicart.com/blog/magento-css/

Comment: Thank you. Adding the css to page.xml does work but i want it for specific modules and pages only like when i call action `helloworld/index/index` the css file is not loaded when i check chrome dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

The path to the `stylesheet` directory will depend on what you have set in **System=>Configuration=>General=>Design=>Themes=>Skin (Images / CSS)** so depending on what you have set there, it will look in that directory for the CSS file.

You can easily find out where Magento is looking for that stylesheet by going on the frontend of the website and looking at the console log, there should be a 404 for the custom.css file.

Always make sure to flush your cache when you make layout changes

Comment: The skin config is empty ,i'm using default magento install with sample data.
And i see not 404 error for the css file in the console.

Comment: did you flush/clear the cache?

Comment: Use i deleted the var cache folder and i have already disabled all cache

Comment: did you try `<action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/custom.css</name></action>`

Comment: It didn't work. Same result :/

Answer (score 0):

> you can try below code this code work for me

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addItem">
        <type>skin_css</type>
        <name>css/custom.css</name>
    </action>
</reference>
```